# jQuery Serialize Form Submission Undefined Index

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, serialization

I'm submitting form using jQuery serialize() function and I'm getting this on PHP page:

```
[data] => title=Demo&days=2;
```

But when I'm using echo or to save `$_POST['days']`value into variable I'm getting  `Undefined index: days`

How to resolve it?

Comment: Serialize means turning something into a string, if you turn something into a string you need to turn it back into an array if you wish to access it like that. Do a var_dump on $_POST and see how the data looks so you can parse it.

Answer (score 0):

If data is the posted variable then you have to parse the string in your PHP script. If it's a GET request and that's the url you need to use $_GET instead.